# What's the relationship between SPDR S&P 500 ETF listings in different countries?

Tags: etf, index-fund

SPDR S&P 500 ETF Trust is listed on four stock exchanges:

- NYSE Arca — Symbol: SPY

  - ISIN: US78462F1030
  - Currency: USD
  - Listing date: 1993-01-22. ([source](https://www.ssga.com/us/en/individual/etfs/funds/spdr-sp-500-etf-trust-spy))
- Singapore Exchange — Symbol: S27

  - ISIN: US78462F1030
  - Currency: USD
  - Listing date: 2001-05-04. ([source](https://www.ssga.com/sg/en/individual/etfs/funds/spdr-sp-500-etf-trust-s27))
- Tokyo Stock Exchange — Symbol: 1557

  - ISIN: US78462F1030
  - Currency: JPY
  - Listing date: 2011-03-24. ([source](https://www.ssga.com/jp/ja/individual/etfs/funds/us-spdr-sp-500-etf-trust-spy))
- Australian Securities Exchange — Symbol: SPY

  - ISIN: AU000000SPY3
  - Currency: AUD
  - Listing date: 2014-10-13. ([source](https://www.ssga.com/au/en_gb/individual/etfs/funds/spdr-sp-500-etf-trust-spy))

What's the relationship between these listings? What are the differences? Do shareholders in Singapore own the same fund as the shareholders in New York? Are the shares fungible between these listing venues?

Answer (score 1):

The listings with the same ISIN (US78462F1030) can be bought and sold at all exchanges which list it, provided your broker has access to them. So with the right broker you can buy them in Singapore and sell in New York.

About the Australian one, I don't know. It might be something like the ADRs in the USA.